# How BinaryFormatter know on DeSerialise which kind of object is hold?

Tags: c#

When doing a DeSerialise using BinaryFormatter, I find out that I get the right object type.

How does the BinaryFormatter keep the right object, even if the object is inherited from another object?  How does it create the right object on the DeSerialise?

example :

```
[Serializable]
public class Class1
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Class2 : Class1
{
    public string Id1 { get; set; }
    public int Age1 { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();

Class1 c1 = new Class1();
Class2 c2 = new Class2();

byte[] c1Bytes;
byte[] c2Bytes;

using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    bf.Serialize(ms, c2);
    c2Bytes = ms.GetBuffer();
}

using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(c2Bytes))
{
    var t = bf.Deserialize(ms);

    string rr = t.ToString();    // rr contain "Class2" 

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the `BinaryFormatter` stores the type information in the serialized data. You can check the format specification [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc236844.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

inspect the contents of c2bytes (use visual studio's memory viewer on the c2bytes variable) and google `.net reflection`